# Java Swing application duplicate session

Tags: java, swing, session

I am not sure if its possible to create a duplicate session on Application.

I have an application developed using Java Swing, which will help to copy contents to the clipboard. I am currently using it as Exe file (converted Jar using Launch4j).

My Concern, I have to add a button or an option that will help me to open a duplicate session of the application on the same machine, like having two applications open at the same time. Is that possible?

Please suggest.

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        String params = null;
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Handoff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always launch another executable from a java program using  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(params)` or other APIs, which you can use to run your binary again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am having difficulty in initializing params. If I initialize as "Null", I am getting null pointer exception when the run the program. I added an option duplicate session as the menu option on the App. So when I click on duplicate session is when I get the run time exception. I have added code above, please suggest

Comment: @sady Why would you try to execute an empty string? How do you expect the `Runtime` class to know what you want to do? Also, do not edit your Question to create a new issue; **first search Stack Overflow** and if not found then post a *new* Question. This Answer by Attias addresses your original Question and should be accepted.

Comment: @BasilBourque Apologize, I made a fool out of myself. I got your point.